# C++ ambiguous constructor when using typedefs

Tags: c++, typedef

Are there any elegant solutions to the following problem involving ambiguous types when overloading functions in C++? I want to have two different types: "distance" and "angle" which semantically mean different things but which may in fact have the same type. When trying to do this in C++ I run up against issues with function overloading:

```
typedef float distance;
typedef float angle;

class Velocity {
public:
    Velocity(distance dx, distance dy) { /* impl */ }
    Velocity(angle theta, distance magnitude) { /* impl */ }
};
```

When I try to compile this, I get "constructor cannot be redeclared". However (for some reason I cannot figure out) when I'm doing this in my actual application code base the class compiles but later on I get a "call to constructor of 'Velocity' is ambiguous" when I'm doing something like this:

```
distance dx;
distance dy;
Velocity v(dx, dy);
```

Are there any elegant solutions to this problem? One unsatisfactory solution would be to just change the type of one of these quantities

```
typedef double distance;
```

but that clearly doesn't scale since there are only a few different floating point types. Another option that I experimented with was using templates

```
template <typename distance, typename angle>
class Velocity {
public:
    Velocity(distance dx, distance dy) : dx(dx), dy(dy) {  }
    Velocity(angle theta, distance magnitude) { }
};
```

but then I get "multiple overloads of 'Velocity' instantiate to the same signature 'void (float, float)'" if I instantiate them with the same type. Even if this worked it would still be a bit unsatisfactory since I would have to add template arguments to `Velocity` types in many places.

Comment: `struct distance { float value; };` and `struct angle { float value; };`

Comment: Ahh I see. That is potentially a good option. It does add the annoyance of having to call `value` everywhere. But I like it. Thank you

Comment: You can embellish the structs with `operator float() const { return value; }` and `distance& operator=(float new_value) { value = new_value; return *this; }` to make them even less bothersome.

Comment: Oh, thats an excellent idea.

Comment: :-)  It has pros and cons.  The more implicit "magic" the class does for you behind your back, the easier it is to have something "funny" and unexpected happen (although it makes perfect sense to the compiler).

Comment: Look [strong typedef](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/boost/strong_typedef.hpp).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`typedef` does not create a new type, it just creates an alias for the type with a different name and possibly in a different namespace, similar to `using`.

As a result both your constructors are effectively `float, float`.

If you want to create an actual new type, you could create a new struct or class containing that type. The C++ chrono types such as `std::chrono::seconds` wrapping an integer. Doing so also allows more specific overloads, for example you might have say `displacement = velocity * time`, although doing so can quickly require many types and operator overloads.

Also be careful when overloading for say `float` and `double`, I would certainly never do it such that they have different meanings. Consider what happens to literals like `0` and `1`, or implicit conversions of types like `int`.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a very light-weight wrapper around distance and angle, and then use literals!

```
struct Distance {
    double value;
};
struct Angle {
    double value;
};

class Velocity {
   public:
    Velocity(Distance dx, Distance dy) { /* impl */ }
    Velocity(Angle theta, Distance magnitude) { /* impl */ }
};
```

Then, you can wrap values when constructing `Velocity`:

```
// Create by distance
Velocity v1(Distance{5.0}, Distance{10.0}); 
// Create by angle
Velocity v2(Angle{1.5}, Distance{1.0});
```

We can also provide user-defined literals so that you can write `v1` and `v2` like this:

```
Velocity v1(5.0_meters, 10.0_meters);
Velocity v2(60.0_degrees, 10.0_meters);
```

Writing a user-defined literal is pretty simple:

```
Distance operator ""_meters(double value) {
    return Distance{value}; 
}
Angle operator ""_degrees(double value) {
    return Angle{value / 180.0 * PI}; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need different types in order to have overloads.

One solution is not to have an overload by changing the function names.

The other is to create your custom type by creating a `class` or a `struct` that wraps the floats.

You can then overload some operators to achieve the desired behavior but in my opinion, is best to change the names of the functions